# Why do some classes require main methods and others do not?

Tags: java, class, oop

I'm currently enrolled in an online Java class, and my instructor has led me to believe that all Java classes must have a main method

ie.

```
public class
{
public static void main(String[] args)
}
```

However, we've just reached a unit on cross referencing classes in other files where this is not the case.

Ex.

```
public class Pie
{

        // declare variables to be called in separate file
        String type;
        int diameter;
        float radius;

}
```

Pie can then be referenced in a fashion such as:

```
Pie newPie = new Pie();

System.out.println("What type of pie will you be eating today?");
        newPie.type = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Ah. " + newPie.type + ". Excellent choice.\n");
```

And this works fine. However the explanation behind why this functions properly eludes me. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: All Java applications _must_ contain at least one class with a main method; but _might_ contain other classes without main methods.

Comment: Either you have misunderstood your instructor or he doesn't know what he's talking about. My money is on the former.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every Java program (which is in turn, built up from one or more Java classes) requires a Main method. The purpose of this special method is to serve as an entry point to your program so that your program can be executed. More information can be found in [this](http://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/KarelJava2ed/ch2/javamain.html) page.

In your `Pie` example, what happens is that when you run your application, the main method will be the first thing which will be called. Once that it will be called, it will create a new `Object`, named `newPie` using the `Pie` template (class) and so on.

Just as extra information, if you are using an IDE, if you add a `main` method in your `Pie` class with the given signature: `public static void main(String[] args)`, the next time you run your program the IDE will ask you to select your entry point since it will have now found two entry points. Once that you will have made your selection, the IDE will make the necessary configurations so that the entry point of your application is noted.

Answer (score 4):

```
my instructor has led me to believe that all Java classes must have a main method
```

this is wrong. It is not necessary for all the classes to have a `main` method. `main` method is used as an entry point for java applications. So once you have entered the java code using main method of a single class you can call other classes code form there.

A better statement would be:

> In the Java programming language, every application must contain a
>   main method, which serves as the entry point of application.

Learn more about main method here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter#MAIN

Answer (score 2):

A Java class and a Java program are two different things.

A Java program contains one or more Java classes, and each class can contain methods and variables. The main method is a special static method that Java recognizes as an entry point in a program (you can think of the main method as a blueprint or set of directions for a program, versus a class being a blueprint of an object like a Pie).

So to answer your question, there's been a misunderstanding. A Java program needs a main method, and a Java class does not necessarily need a main method.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to have `main` method in every java class `main` method is the entry point of java application. There can be a `class` without `main` method.

Answer (score 0):

they are different ,

typically you created class in your app to store some data

but there is another class that is your main class which will launch your app and your app start will be there and call another class