# I am unsure of where to up Static void main

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MethodHolder {

    private static int nextShopperID = 100;
    private static int nextProductID = 100;

    protected static Shopper generateShopper() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Name: ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Balance: ");
        double balance = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Product Limit: ");
        int productLimit = scan.nextInt();

        // Increment the shopper ID and return a new Shopper object
        return new Shopper(nextShopperID++, name, balance, productLimit);
    }

    protected static Product generateProduct() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Name: ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Department: ");
        String department = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Description: ");
        String description = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Price: ");
        double price = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Initial Count: ");
        int initialCount = scan.nextInt();

        // Increment the product ID and return a new Product object
        return new Product(nextProductID++, name, department, description, price, initialCount);
    }

    protected static void printShopperInfo(Shopper s) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + s.getName());
        System.out.println("Products Bought: " + s.getProductsBought());
        System.out.println("Can Still Buy: " + (s.getProductLimit() - s.getProductsBought()));
        System.out.println("Spent So Far: $" + s.getSpentSoFar());
        System.out.println("Balance Remaining: $" + s.getBalance());
        System.out.println("Products Purchased: ");
        s.printProducts();
    }

    protected static void printProductInfo(Product p) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + p.getName());
        System.out.println("Department: " + p.getDepartment());
        System.out.println("Description: " + p.getProductDescription());
        System.out.println("Price: $" + p.getPrice());
        System.out.println("Number Bought: " + p.getNumberBought());
        System.out.println("Number Remaining: " + (p.getInitialCount() - p.getNumberBought()));
        System.out.println("Product Bought By: ");
        p.printShoppers();
    }

    protected static void doPurchase(Shopper s, Product p) {
        if (s.canAdd() && p.canAdd()) {
            if (s.addProduct(p) && p.addShopper(s))
                System.out.println(s.getName() + " has purchased " + p.getName());
            else
                System.out.println(s.getName() + "'s purchase of " + p.getName() +
                        " could not be completed");
        } else {
            if (!s.canAdd())
                System.out.println(s.getName() + " cannot purchase any more items");
            if (!p.canAdd())
                System.out.println("There are no more of " + p.getName() + " in the store");
        }
    }
}
```

Currently running this code connected to 3 other scripts but when I run it I am getting

```
"Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[]."
```

What is wrong?

I read the it should be Static Void main but I am unsure of where to put it.

Comment: JavaScript is not Java.

Comment: Your *.class file that you need to run  should have at least one class with `main` method.  That's where JVM will start to run your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do some classes require main methods and others do not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106744/why-do-some-classes-require-main-methods-and-others-do-not)

Comment: Java classes are not "scripts".

Comment: That error will be raised by the JVM when you launch it with an entry-point class that does not declare a suitable `main()` method.  For example, `java i.dont.HaveAMain`.  It's not clear in your case whether it is `MethodHolder` or some other class that you're trying to use as an entry point, but whatever class it is, what do you expect the JVM to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

You must add this method in your class

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // put some logic here
  }
```

so your class will be like that:

```
public class MethodHolder {
     

  //your methodes here

 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
  }
}
```